# Finding a particular instance in an associated model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, instance

I have two models

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :dogs
end

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
end
```

and the tutorials I've seen always created a new instance (through build) of the associated model (@dog.build_owner in the code below)

```
class DogsController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @dog = Dog.new
   @dog.build_owner 
  end
 end
```

**Is there a way to find an existing model instance (a particular owner in this case) and associate it when creating a new Dog?** instead of creating a new owner every time.

My form looks like this:

```
<h1>Create a new Dog:</h1>
<%= form_for(@dog) do |f|%>
    
  <div>
    <%= f.label :breed%>
    <%= f.text_field :breed%>
  </div><br>
    
  <div>
    <%= f.label :age%>
    <%= f.text_field :age%>
  </div><br>
    
    <div>
    <h3>Create a new owner:</h3>
     <%= f.fields_for :owner, Owner.new do |owner_attributes|%>
      <%= owner_attributes.label :name, "Owner Name:" %>
      <%= owner_attributes.text_field :name %>
     <% end %>
    </div>
    
  <%= f.submit %>
    
<% end %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried Owner.find_by_name!(params[:name]) if the record is found use the same object in create method in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to use here is [ActiveRecord::Relations#find_or_create_by](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by).  In your controller, you'll get the name of the owner through your form, and you'll pass that into the `find_or_create_by` method like so:

```rb
@dog = Dog.new
@dog.owner.find_or_create_by(name: params.dig(:owner, :name))
```

This method will set the `owner` of the new instance of `Dog` to either the `Owner` that already exists with the name provided, or go ahead and create the new entry in the database and assign the association for you.

Something you probably want to do with this too is to go ahead and make sure that `Owner#name` is forced to be unique.  `find_or_create_by` makes some pretty strong assumptions that there will only every be one instance of what you're looking for, so if there are multiple, you can get indeterminate results.  To guarantee uniqueness of name in the `Owner` class, you add the following validation

```rb
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :dogs

 # uniqueness validation of name
 validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```